# How to set cooldown period for the Kops cluster autoscaler?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kops

The autoscaler plugin works great, but it defaults to a 10 minute cooldown for unneeded nodes. Since AWS has per-second billing, we'd like to scale down faster to reduce cost.

Is the cooldown period configurable in the kops InstanceGroup or the cluster autoscaler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `--scale-down-unneeded-time` flag while defining autoscaler in deployment configuration file:

Here is an example:

```
 command:
   - ./cluster-autoscaler
   - --cloud-provider=aws
   - ...
   - --scan-interval=25s
   - --scale-down-unneeded-time=30s
```

It is useful to add also `--scan-interval` flag.

**Also remember that short cooldowns can cause Over-Scaling / Under-Scaling.**

Cooldown durations should instead be *at least* the amount of time it takes the target metric to reach its new “normal” after a scaling event. If it takes three minutes for your CPU utilization to drop by about 50% after scaling up 2x, a cooldown less than three minutes causes AWS to scale out again before the previous scale out has had time to take effect on your metrics, causing it to scale out more than necessary.

Take a look: [autoscaling-aws](https://segment.com/blog/when-aws-autoscale-doesn-t/), [kubernetes-autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#i-have-a-couple-of-nodes-with-low-utilization-but-they-are-not-scaled-down-why), [autoscaler-aws-kubernetes](https://d1.awsstatic.com/events/reinvent/2019/REPEAT_3_Deep_dive_Kubernetes_auto_scaling_CON418-R3.pdf).

Comment: IMO, `--scan-interval=25s` is not better. Keep it default to `10s` or less is more responsive.

Comment: Hi, @RammusXu it was just an example. This flag is really useful that's why I added it. How many seconds you will set up is up to you. As you said by default it is  10 seconds. Lower value is also better but I adjusted this value to scale-down-unneeded-time.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#i-have-a-couple-of-nodes-with-low-utilization-but-they-are-not-scaled-down-why

> node was unneeded for less than 10 minutes (configurable by --scale-down-unneeded-time flag)

So, it will like be

```yaml
          command:
            - ./cluster-autoscaler
            ...
            - --scale-down-unneeded-time=5m
```